# Two-way binding for select element doesn't work properly | Angular 11

Tags: angular, two-way-binding, angular2-ngmodel

I have a JSON with structure:

For `item`

```
"item": {
        "pk": "123456",
        "title": "Title4",
        "list_fields": [
            {
                "pk": "12345",
                "title": "Selector",
                "type": "SEL",
                "position": 1,
                "locked": true,
                "value": {
                        "pk": 567,
                        "value": "Finished",
                        "position": 3,
                        "color": "FF0000"
                }
            }
        ]           
    },
```

For its selectors

```
"field": {
  "pk": "12345",
  "type": "SEL",
  "locked": true,
  "position": 1,
  "values": [
      {
          "pk": 123,
          "value": "Not Started",
          "position": 1,
          "color": "FF0000"
      },
      {
          "pk": 345,
          "value": "In Process",
          "position": 2,
          "color": "FF0000"
      },
      {
          "pk": 567,
          "value": "Finished",
          "position": 3,
          "color": "FF0000"
      }
    ]
}
```

So, I trying to make a simple selector, where I can see current `list_fields` values, that a part of `field`

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let list_field of item.list_fields">

            <select [(ngModel)]="list_field.value" [name]="list_field.pk" [id]="list_field.pk">
                <option disabled>Select value</option>
                <option *ngFor="let val of field.values" [ngValue]="val">{{ val.value }}</option>
            </select>
        
    </ng-container>
```

When I made this selector, I got issue: when page loads, selector is empty (looks like, current value doest bind to select element via `[(ngModel)]`)

[image: selector is empty, but item have initial value]

But when I start to select value from select dropdown, selected value bind to item with no problem.

What am I need to do to bind CURRENT value to selector, when page loads?

Comment: you have not set any initial value list_field.value is undefined

Comment: Initial value was on init. You can see initial value in on screenshot and inside JSON example: `{"pk": 567,"value": "Finished","position": 3,"color": "FF0000"}`

Comment: Looks like a problem occurring because I trying to operate with whole object inside selector, but not with a unique value (like `pk`) inside of it. When I trying to operate with `value.pk` in selector and inside `ngModel` - all works fine. But I NEED to operate with a whole object...

Comment: if you use ngValue the selected value must base the same object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use **ngValue** as the value of the option this mean you need to set `list_field.value` as one of the **field.values** object because the selected value compared base of object reference

```js
ngOnInit(){
this.field.value = this.field.values[2];
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngvalue?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Yes, in order to question - its worked, thank you. But model is too flexible to perform such tasks on init: a lot fields may be there.

So, my solution was to use `value.pk` inside selector, detect selector change with `(change)` and change whole object, using `value.pk` to find that object inside `this.field.values`